# Is resource.data and request.resource.data the same thing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I watched Firebase's official guide and the impression I got was `request.resource.data` points to the new data being written. However, when I'm testing in the emulator, `request.resource.data` exists no matter what I send, and always equals `resource.data`. I read the documentation and it's a little round about.

If these values should should be the same, how do I interpret this snippet from the guide

```typescript
    allow create: if 
    request.resource.data.score is number &&
    request.resource.data.score >=1 &&
    request.resource.data.score <=5 &&
```

This was said to prevent users from sending invalid 1-5 star ratings for a restaurant. However, per what I understand from the emulator, this validates the already existing data and not the incoming.

Link to moment in video:
https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw?t=628

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a create/update/delete operation `request.resource` refers to the document as it'll exist after the operation (if the operation succeeds), while `resource` refers to the document as it exists before the operation.

So (only) if your write operation makes no change whatsoever, will they be exactly the same.

From the documentation on [data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation):

> The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. For more information on the `resource` variable, see the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource).
>
> When writing data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document. For update operations that only modify a subset of the document fields, the `request.resource` variable will contain the pending document state after the operation. You can check the field values in `request.resource` to prevent unwanted or inconsistent data updates:
>
> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
>     // the name is not changed
>     match /cities/{city} {
>       allow update: if request.resource.data.population > 0
>                     && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense. I was updating a subset of the data. So, as you clarified, the contents weren't always equal, but I was confused why the extra stuff was there.